# Как изменить класс Div который fixed, при прокрутке на 570px. какой будет javascript код

Tags: javascript, css

Как изменить класс Div который fixed, при прокрутке на 570px. какой будет javascript код. Я нашел статью в интернете, но они меняют стиль дива, вот код:

```
if ((typeof window.pageYOffset != 'undefined' ? window.pageYOffset: document.documentElement.scrollTop? document.documentElement.scrollTop: document.body.scrollTop? document.body.scrollTop:0) >= 570) {
      $("div #true").css({
        'background-color':'#54a58b'
      });
};
```

Как изменить код, чтобы он менял класс дива

Comment: jQuery используете? С ним будет проще работать с событиями прокрутки. Могу набросать пример на codepen.

Comment: давайте. если можно конечно

Comment: почему в css #nav-fixed.active?

Comment: как сделать чтобы прост .active был

Comment: >> Как изменить класс Div который fixed, при прокрутке на 570px << в примере и изменил на .active исходя из вашего вопроса. В css ставлю стили для #nav-fixed.active, в каком смысле почему? Ну так напиши просто .active

Comment: но тогда js надо менять ато оно не работает

Comment: в примере я добавил класс к элементу, работайте с этим классом прописывая стили в css

Comment: Ок спасибо за помощь)

Comment: ок, отметьте правильный ответ,  если не сложно :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Пример реализации вашей задачи на jQuery:

Демо: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZEPPz

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  var height = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('#nav-fixed')[height >= 570 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('active').text(height+'px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Замените `$("div #true").css({ 'background-color':'#54a58b' });` на `$("div #true").addClass('имя_класса');`

Comment: Спасибо вам!! !!!

Comment: я так написал, но при прокручиваю 570 px, див начинает гнать, меняет только цвет текста, и начинает моргать.. как решить??

Comment: Используете `addClass()` или `toggleClass()`? Нужно первое (addClass())

Comment: Если меняется только цвет текста, значит, скорее всего, ошибка в css (не указали для класса остальные свойства)

Comment: попробывал с Addclass(), но оно только меняет текст в диве. а сам div background-color не меняет

Comment: Это уже вопрос оформления через стили. Добавляйте в правило для класса изменение не только цвета текста, но и цвета фона `.class_name {color: #код_цвета; background-color: #54a58b;}`

Comment: addclass() как я понел, добавляет класс диву, но предыдущий класс не удаляет да?

Comment: Да, правильно. Вообще, выше очень хороший пример кода вам привели. Советую воспользоваться им :)